# How do I get a file's directory using the File object?

Tags: java, file

Consider the code:

```
File file = new File("c:\\temp\\java\\testfile");
```

`testfile` is a file, and it may or may not exist.
I want to get the directory `c:\\temp\\java\\` using the `File` object.  How do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 197, accepted):

In either case, I'd expect [`file.getParent()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#getParent()) (or [`file.getParentFile()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#getParentFile())) to give you what you want.

Additionally, if you want to find out whether the original `File` *does* exist and *is* a directory, then `exists()` and `isDirectory()` are what you're after.

Comment: Use file.getParent() carefully, because it may return null in some cases.

Comment: @geschema Ponaguynik's answer below addresses this

Comment: This (and all other current answers as of posting) fail to give the parent directory (in terms of the filesystem) if the given file is eg.
new File("." + File.separator + ".");
See my answer below for a more robust solution if needed

Comment: `System.out.println(new File("\\myfile.txt").getParentFile().getAbsolutePath());` correctly prints "C:\" but careful when you're using a `File` with a path like that because some libraries that write/read files might not be able to handle paths starting with an e.g. backslash or a ".." (which is also theoretically valid). It's best to check all the possibilities mentioned [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/file-path-formats).

Answer (score 27):

[File.getParent()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html#getParent--) from Java Documentation

Answer (score 26):

If you do something like this:

```
File file = new File("test.txt");
String parent = file.getParent();
```

`parent` will be null.

So to get directory of this file you can do next:

```
parent = file.getAbsoluteFile().getParent();
```

Answer (score 9):

File API [File.getParent](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/File.html#getParent()) or [File.getParentFile](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/File.html#getParentFile()) should return you Directory of file.

Your code should be like :

```
    File file = new File("c:\\temp\\java\\testfile");
    if(!file.exists()){
        file = file.getParentFile();
    }
```

You can additionally check your parent file is directory using [File.isDirectory](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/File.html#isDirectory()) API

```
if(file.isDirectory()){
    System.out.println("file is directory ");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

> ```
> File directory = new File("Enter any 
>                 directory name or file name");
> boolean isDirectory = directory.isDirectory();
> if (isDirectory) {
>   // It returns true if directory is a directory.
>   System.out.println("the name you have entered 
>          is a directory  : "  +    directory);  
>   //It returns the absolutepath of a directory.
>   System.out.println("the path is "  + 
>               directory.getAbsolutePath());
> } else {
>   // It returns false if directory is a file.
>   System.out.println("the name you have
>    entered is a file  : " +   directory);
>   //It returns the absolute path of a file.
>   System.out.println("the path is "  +  
>             file.getParent());
> }
> ```

Comment: You do not answer the question, this does not work for a file.

Comment: `code` final File file = new File("C:/dev/changeofseasons.mid");
System.out.println("file exists? " + file.exists());
System.out.println("directory of file: " + file.getAbsolutePath());

Ok, sorry for lame indenting, I don't think it is possible to format code in comments. Still, your code obviously does not work.

Answer (score 3):

```
File filePath=new File("your_file_path");
String dir="";
if (filePath.isDirectory())
{
    dir=filePath.getAbsolutePath();
}
else
{
    dir=filePath.getAbsolutePath().replaceAll(filePath.getName(), "");
}
```

Comment: Descriptions are needed.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  In general, code answers need a little explanation - see this meta [Stackoverflow post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260413/838992).  With the answer you've posted, you might need to explain you're trying to give a general case and how it relates to the OP's actual post.  More seriously - you might want to consider how it would work on `your_file_path = "C:\\testfiles\\temp\\testfile";` - I don't think it would give what you hope.

Answer (score 1):

```
String parentPath = f.getPath().substring(0, f.getPath().length() - f.getName().length());
```

This would be my solution

Answer (score 0):

6/10/2021 All current answers fail if eg. the given file is...

```
new File("." + File.separator + "."); //Odd, yes, but I've seen similar more often than you'd think is possible
```

For a simple, robust solution, try...

```
File givenFile = new File("." + File.separator + ".." + File.separator + "." + File.separator + "fakeFilename"); //The file or dir we want the parent of, whether it exists or not
File parentFile = new File(givenFile.getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + "..");
System.out.println(parentFile.getAbsolutePath());
```

Note that this answer assumes you want *the actual parent directory on the filesystem*, and not *a File object representing the parent node of the given File object* (which may be null, or may be the same directory as the given file).

EDIT: Also note that the internal filename is not succinct, and could in some cases grow with repeated usage.  An equivalent solution without that issue would need to parse the entire absolute filename given by the above solution, and adjust the output, removing all instances of "." and ".." (the latter ofc would need to also remove the node before it, but only after all "." are removed)

Answer (score -1):

You can use this

```
 File dir=new File(TestMain.class.getClassLoader().getResource("filename").getPath());
```

Answer (score -1):

I found this more useful for getting the absolute file location.

```
File file = new File("\\TestHello\\test.txt");
System.out.println(file.getAbsoluteFile());
```