# how to get the DIR of the user folder?

Tags: java, dir

Hello all well I'm trying to get the DIR of the user folder which is practically located at :

c:/Users/userName/

but the userName is different from one user to the other of course, so how would i get the DIR of the folder?

I know for the desktop directory its getHomeDirectory() , is there something similar to this folder?

thanks.

Comment: Have you tried `System.getProperty("user.home")`?

Answer (score 0):

This answer might help you [How do I get a file's directory using the File object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3657157/how-do-i-get-a-files-directory-using-the-file-object), i would suggest you to have a look at file class method's also