# Where should I place a text file for netbeans to read?

Tags: java, netbeans

I am new to java but I have looked for an answer but unfortunately haven't found one specific to my situation. I'd like to know where to place my file "icecream.txt" so that netbeans can read it. My programs works if I code the absolute the path but I'd prefer not to do that as it needs to run on the other student's computers without changes. I have attached an image of where I have placed my file. Any help would be appreciated.
[neatbeans file folders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PsuT6.png)

My code is bellow if that helps

```
package icecreamsales;
/**
 *
 * @author anonymous
 */
public class IceCreamSales {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
             TextIO.readFile("icecream.txt");
        }
        catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            System.out.println("Can't open file \"icecream.txt\" for reading!");
            System.out.println("Please make sure the file is present before");
            System.out.println("running the program.");
            System.exit(1);  // Terminates the program.
    }

        int totalIceCreamSales = 0;
        int strawberryIceCreamSales = 0;

        while (!TextIO.eof()) {
            String readLines = TextIO.getln();
            totalIceCreamSales++;

            if (readLines.equals("Strawberry")) {
                 strawberryIceCreamSales++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Icecream cone sales totalled " + totalIceCreamSales);
        System.out.println("Strawberry icecream sales totalled " + strawberryIceCreamSales);
        System.out.println("Strawberry icecream is " + ((double) strawberryIceCreamSales/totalIceCreamSales*100) + "%%" + " of total sales");
   }
}
```

Comment: where-ever you choose.

Comment: Thanks @Stultuske. I placed the file in what I thought was the appropriate place and my program throws an exception.

Comment: there is no "appropriate" place, there is the place you decide on. anyway, run: File f = new File("myText.txt"); and print the path of that file out, it should tell you what you need

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to move the file `icecream.txt` into the netbeans project. For e.g.

```
IceCreamSales (Project)
  |
  +--icecream.txt
  |
  +--src
      |
      +--icecreamsales
            |
            +--IceCreamSales.java
```

Answer (score 0):

Just as @Stultuske said, you can place your text file anywhere. You can even dedicate a folder for future text files. You just have to know it's specific directory / location so that the "program" will know where to find those files needed.

Look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3657157/how-do-i-get-a-files-directory-using-the-file-object) for file directories references

Comment: thanks Scar and @Stultuske my program now works as it should. However, I was not really able to get either of your answers working properly, I guess I need to know a little more java first. I did find project locations though and copied my file in the top level of the src folder. Last time I just dragged and dropped my file into netbeans so I guess that might have been the cause of my issues. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

## How to use Text Files Appropriately

First make a text file INSIDE Windows Explorer, make sure it's not in the package (NOT inside NetBeans).
The IDE I used was NetBeans.
The 'class name' and package must be named EXACTLY the same.
If the class name isn't the same with package name it'll NOT work.
Name package before using, and 'refactor' after right-clicking on package.

Readfile = where the input is being received and returned.
Writefile = where the output is being returned and received.

```
package Project;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

public class Project {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String newReader = "read.txt";
        String newWriter = "write.txt";
        try {             
            FileReader reader = new FileReader(newReader);
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(reader);
            FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(newWriter);
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(writer);
            String line = null;
            int numLines = 0;
            while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                out.println(line.toUpperCase());
                ++numLines;
            }
            in.close();
            out.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("ERROR!" + e);
        }
    }
}
```

C:\Users\abdul\OneDrive\Documents\NetBeansProjects\DadsProject

Make sure it's under the DadsProject (folder name), or under the folder of the name of the project you're working on.

C:\Users\abdul\OneDrive\Documents\NetBeansProjects\DadsProject\read * 'read' is the text file in this example

The file "read" is a text file make sure it has NO ".txt" attached as such when it's in 'WindowsExplorer'.
You do NOT need the text file to be in 'NetBeans' just in 'WindowsExplorer' and that'll suffice.
Make sure it's under 'DadsProject' and above 'src' (literally inside 'DadsProject' like so).

C:\Users\abdul\OneDrive\Documents\NetBeansProjects\DadsProject\src

Make sure it's above 'src' under 'DadsProject'

Make sure the file is .txt when it's in your code.
For example:

String reader = "read.txt"; must have .txt or else it won't work

For example:
Yes, to this => read (this is a text file)
No, to this => read.txt (this is also a different text file)
WARNING!!!
read (text file) and read.txt (text file).
They're NOT the same type of 'text file'.